# how to configure spark sql thrift server

Tags: apache-spark, spark-thriftserver

I am trying to install apache thrift server .
I installed spark,hadoop and yarn.
I configured hive metastore and successfully started both metastore
and hiveserver2: 
nohup hive --service metastore > /var/log/hive/metastore.log &
nohup hive --service hiveserver2 > /var/log/hive/hiveserver2.log &

hiveserver2 now listens on port 10000.

when I am trying to start spark thrift server I am running :
sbin/start-thriftserver.sh  --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host ycsb-vanilla-master --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port 10001
but am unable to connect. 
I've seen that most of the examples use port 10000,but the port is already taken by hiveserver2.

Running beeline connects with : !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000

but unable to connect with : !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001

Trying to connect with simba retrieves errornum=10061, What am I missing ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try copying the `hive-site.xml` from hive conf directory to spark conf directory with changed port for thrift? After conpying this, you will need to run `sbin/start-thriftserver.sh` without any params.

Comment: Thank you!, it solved the problem. when updating the hive the problem was solved!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply make spark-thrift server run on another port by:

```sh
sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port 8088
```